# How to solve the problem on number theory

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find the number of positive integer pairs $x,y$ such that

$$xy+\dfrac{(x^3+y^3)}3=2007.$$

I solved the question by using factorization and further checking possible values of $x$ and $y$. But it was very lengthy as I had to check many cases for $x$ and $y$. Is there any possible other method?

Comment: write your solution dovn.

Comment: What pairs did you find by this method?

Comment: after solving i got (x+y-1)(x^2+y^2+1+x+y-xy)=6020 further 6020=2^2*5*7*43 and as x+y-1 less than other term we get possible values of x+y-1 as 2,5,14,20,35 amd further on inspection I found only 20 as possible value and futher on solving I got (18,3) and (3,18) as the answer

Comment: It is better to edit an existing post rather then to repost. Please keep this in mind for the future. This time I deleted the other one.

Comment: Well see the $\frac *3$ makes me think in terms of $\mod 3$ and when you have a hammer everything looks like a nail.  Think of $\mod 3$.  That severely limits your testing.

Answer (score 2):

Idea:

$$ 3xy+(x+y)(x^2-xy+y^2)=6021$$ so
$$ 3xy+(x+y)(x+y)^2-2xy(x+y)=6021$$ Now let $a=x+y$ and $b=xy$. Then $$ a^3-6021=3b(a-1)$$
so $3\mid a$ so $a=3c$ and know we have $$9(c^3-223) =b(3c-1)$$ so $9\mid b$ so $b=9d$ and thus $$c^3-223 =d(3c-1)\implies 3c-1\mid c^3-223$$

---

---

I thought that this with $c$ will go faster than with $a$, so I deleted it. Anway here is what I have before:

so $$a-1\mid a^3-6021\;\;\;\;{\rm in}\;\;\;\; 3\mid a$$
Since $a-1\mid a^3-1$ we have $$a-1\mid 6020\implies $$ $$a-1\in \{1,2,4,5,7,10,14,20,28,35, 43,70,86,140,172,215,301,430, 
602,860,1202,1505, 3010,6020\}$$
so $$a\in \{2,3,5,6,8,11,15,21,29,36, 44,71,87,141,173,216,302,431, 
603,861,1203,1506, 3011,6021\}$$ so

$$a\in \{3,6,15,21,36,87,141,216,603,861,1203,1506,6021\}$$

Answer (score 1):

Another possible way:

- multiply the equation by $3 $.
- show that $ x =-y\ \bmod 3 $ using FLT.
- rule out the cases $1 $ and $2 $, so that $3\mid x$
- the equation is now $ kl+k^3+l^3=223 $.
- perfect cubes close enough to $223 $ are few, one easily checks that $(6, 1) $ and $(1, 6) $ are the only solutions as you found. Congrats.

Comment: The question asks for integer solutions. It appears that in your last bullet point, you are assuming $k,l$ are nonnegative. Unless you can prove that $k,l$ _must_ be nonnegative, I don't see the validity of your argument.

Comment: @quasi From the OP, "*Find the number of positive integer pairs*"

Comment: Ah, yes, I see. Sorry. The OP posted a later question (now deleted), and _almost_ a duplicate of this one, and in that question, there was an image of the actual question (presumably from a contest), which specified _integer_ solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Denote: $$\begin{cases}x+y=a \\ x-y=b\end{cases} \Rightarrow \begin{cases} x=\frac{a+b}{2}\\ y=\frac{a-b}{2}\end{cases}$$ Then:
$$xy+\dfrac{x^3+y^3}3=2007 \Rightarrow (a+2)^2+3b^2=\frac{24080}{a-1}.$$
Note that $a>1$ and $a$ can be $2,3, 5,6,8,9,11, 15,17,21$. Note that $a\ge 28 \Rightarrow b^2<0$. So, among them only $21$ suits. Hence $b=15$. Hence: $(x,y)=(18,3)$. Since the equation is symmetric, $(x,y)=(3,18)$.

Comment: Nice solution!${}{}{}{}$

Comment: @quasi, thank you!

Comment: $x+y$ must be multiple of $3$, dear friend.

Comment: @Piquito, yes, is it not? Can you be more specific, please?

Comment: @farruhota: My comment was not an objection. Regards.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that screams at me is $3|x^3 + x^3$ so

$x^3 \equiv -y^3 \mod 3$ so $x\equiv -y \mod 3$

Let $x \equiv i \mod 3$ and $y \equiv -i \mod 3$.  If $x = 3k + i$ and $y = 3j -i$ then $\frac {x^3 + y^3}{3} = 9(k^3 + j^k) + 9(k^2i-j^2i)+3(ki -ji) + \frac {i^3 - i^3}3 \equiv 0 \mod 3$

So $xy + \frac  {x^3 + y^3}3 \equiv i^2 \mod 3$ and $2007\equiv 0 \mod 3$ so $i = 0$ and $3|x$ and $3|y$.

Let $x = 3a$ and $y = 3b$ and we get

$9ab + 9(a^3 + b^3) = 2007$ so

$ab + a^3 + b^3 = 223$

Hmmm, still trial and error but $b^3, a^3 < \sqrt[3]223 \approx 6$ so not *too* many to test.

One of $a$ or $b$ must be odd. We have $ab + a^3 + b^3\equiv ab + a +b \equiv 1 \mod 3$:  That means:

$(a,b)\equiv (0, k) \to 0*k + 0 + k\equiv k \mod 3$

So $a\equiv 0$ (wolog) and $b \equiv 1$ is possible.

$(a,b) \equiv (1,1) \to 1 + 1 + 1 \equiv 0 \mod 3$.

$(a,b) \equiv (1,-1) \to -1 + 1 + -1 \equiv -1 \mod 3$.

$(a,b) \equiv (-1,-1) \to 1 -1 -1 \equiv -1 \mod 3$.

So $a \equiv 0$ and $b \equiv 1$ and at least one is odd.

So

$[0,1],[3,1],[3,4],[6,1]$ are the only four options.

Obviously if the average of $ab, a^3, b^3$ is $\frac {223}3 \approx 70 > 4^3$, the first three can't possibly work.  Don't even need to test them.

So $[6,1]$ is only option.

An indeed $6 + 6^3 + 1 = 223$.

So, if my reasoning is right (which.... I really don't see any error or faulty assumptions... but ... a self-editor is always blind....).  $\{x,y\} = \{18,3\}$ are the only solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I show here that the only correct answer is, as it maintain  @fleablood and @farruhota in their answers.
$$\frac{x^3+y^3}{3}=\frac{(x+y)^3}{3}-xy(x+y)\Rightarrow xy+\frac{(x+y)^3}{3}-xy(x+y)=2007$$ It follows $x+y\equiv 0\pmod3$.
The cubic $$xy+\frac{x^3+y^3}{3}=2007$$ is symmetric respect to the diagonal $y=x$  then if the line $x + y = 3a$ cuts the cubic at the point $(x, y)$ it also cuts it at the point $(y, x)$. The system
$$\begin{cases}x+y=3a\\xy+\dfrac{x^3+y^3}{3}=2007\end{cases}$$ has a solving equation of the second degree whose solution $(x,y)$ (and the symmetric $(y,x))$ is$$\begin{cases}x=\dfrac{3(-3a^2+a+X)}{2-6a}\\y=\dfrac{3(3a^2-+Xa+X)}{2-6a}\end{cases}\quad\text{ where } X=\sqrt{-3a^4-2a^3+a^2+2676a-892}$$ It follows that there are quite few values of $a$ giving real roots. In the attached  graph of the cubic, only the black lines $x + y = 21,24,27$ (corresponding to $a=7,8,9$) cut the curve in real positive points. For $a\le6$ and $a\ge10$ does not. For the line $x+y=18$ the red points of intersection are not in the first quadrant (approximately $(18.204,-0.204)$).

Finally we have just three candidates (and the symmetric) produced by the lines $x+y=21,24,27$ but only the line $x+y=21$  agrees with the requirement of positive integers for the intersection.  In this line we have marked all the points of integer coordinates  of the first quadrant (in red those of intersection with the cubic). These three candidates are
$$(18,3)\quad\text{ and approximately }\quad(17.56,6.44),(16.162,10.838).$$
Thus the only solutions are given by $\{18,3\}$.

[image]